# In React I18next, first initialization, shown json key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next

To internationalization, I used i18next.

I have experience to use i18next jQuery and ReactJS.

Now I used [i18next for ReactJS](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next).

But I have a problem.

In jQuery, the Value can be set as a default value.

For example

```
<!-- Standard -->
<li data-i18n="nav.home"></li>

<!-- below code also available -->
<li data-i18n="nav.home">MY HOME</li>
```

Above code, It's applied "HOME" as default value.

BUT React-i18n, can't set default value.

Therefore when first initialization web page, shown Json key split second.

Like this

```
<!-- set a -->
const {t} = this.props;
<li>{ t(nav.home) }</li>
```

**I don't want to see json key.** I just want to see loaded value ("MY HOME") directly.

You can see this problem as [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VQolLweM6M) that I uploaded

Alternatively I choose my solution to use [i18next event listener](http://i18next.com/docs/api/#on-initialized).

```
// In constructor
this.state = { i18nLoaded : false }

// In componentWillMount
i18next.on('initialized', () => {
    this.setState({ i18nLoaded : true })
});

// In Render
const {t} = this.props;
return (
    <div>
        {
            this.state.i18nLoaded ? 
                <li>{ t(nav.home) }</li> 
            : ""
        }
    </div>
)
```

I choose the method that rendering component after i18next initialization using Event Listener. But It looks like incompleteness.

Does anyone know the solution about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To set a default Value in react-i18n, using options.
[i18next API](http://i18next.com/docs/options/#t-options)

```
const {t} = this.props;
<li>{ t(nav.home, {defaultValue : "MY HOME"}) }</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution would be using react-i18next: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next

There you can set wait flag on the translate hoc.